# How to invoke 32-bit Internet explorer on 64 bit machine for selenium

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to invoke 32-bit Internet explorer on 64 bit machine for selenium WebDriver so that `sendKeys()` function will perform smoothly? I am using Maven Project with following dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code for Initiate IE Browser as follows:

```
public WebDriver launchIEBrowser() {
    syso("IE Browser");
    InternetExplorerDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    syso("IE browser Launched successfully");
    return driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [download](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) the 32 bit `driver server`. It's compatible with 64 bit machine.